Laravel Event is not working on broadcasting
I'm trying to create a laravel websocket using pusher + laravel-echo and vue+vite for frontend.
I used this guide for configuring websockets. The problem is that if I create an event on pusher Debug console with this params Channel: comments, Event: newComment - it will console.log this event on my site, but my real event isn't showing.
This is my event:
class CommentCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    protected $comment;

    public function __construct($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'comment' => $this->comment,
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'newComment';
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('comments');
    }
}

I create this event in my CommentController.php like this:
private function storeComment(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::firstOrCreate(
            ['email' => $request['email']],
            ['username' => $request['username']]
        );

        $filePath = null;
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $fileName = uniqid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filePath = 'comments/' . $fileName;
            $file->storeAs('comments', $fileName);
        }

        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->user_id = $user->id;
        $comment->parent_id = $request->parent_id == 'null' ? null : $request->parent_id;
        $comment->home_page = $request->homepage;
        $comment->text = $request->text;
        $comment->rating = 0;
        $comment->file_path = $filePath;
        $comment->created_at = now();
        $comment->save();

        event(new CommentCreated($request->get('comment'))); //event created


        Cache::forget('comments_' . 'created_at' . '_desc' . '_1');


        return response()->json("Comment saved", 201);
    }

And on frontend I listen to event like this:
 mounted() {
      Echo.channel('comments')
                .listen('.newComment', (comment) => {
                    console.log('New comment created:', comment);
                });
        }

I'm sure that problem is with event, not pusher configuration, otherwise if I created a new event on pusher debug console - it wouldn't show on my site, so listening to event is configured correctly. I'm new to Laravel and I really hope that you would help me find what's wrong. Thanks in advance :)

The problem was me not running laravel queues. I just needed to run this command: pm2 start "php artisan queue:work" --name "queue"
